# How does MySQL determine host of client when connecting remotely?

Tags: mysql, ip, client, remote-access, hostname

I'm trying to establish a connection to a MySQL server on a remote host. Both machines are running RH 7.5 and MySQL 5.7.

I *can* connect to the server as a root user. I did that, and used it to set up a secondary user like this:

```
CREATE USER 'foo'@'client-ip-address' identified by 'my-password';
```

and then

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my-db.* to 'foo'@'client-ip-addres';
```

That all went fine. But to my surprise, when I tried to connect using this new user, I got an error I wasn't used to:

```
$ mysql -u foo -h server-ip-address -pmy-password my-db
Access denied for user 'foo'@'some-hostname-not-an-ip.com' (using password: YES)
```

I know the IP address of the client (where I'm connecting *from*), which is why I set up the user with that value in the "host" column on the server. But the client is obviously trying to establish a connection using a value for "host" that is not the IP address. Instead it's some hostname, and not an IP address at all.

Where is this value coming from? How does mysql determine its own host when it tries to connect to a remote server? In the past I've only ever seen it use the machine's own IP address.

Comment: The 'some-hostname-not-an-ip.com' comes from the mysql server doing a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address of your client IP address. Perhaps you are behind a NAT gateway, so the server sees some other IP address than the local IP address of your client. Or look for duplicate privileges that someone might have added either on the 'some-hostname-not-an-ip.com' or the 'client-ip-address'

Comment: Thank you, nos, for your response. Is there no way to tell the MySQL server to just use the IP address as the "host" instead of doing a reverse DNS lookup on it?

Comment: MySQL will use the IP address. When that failed, it did a reverse DNS lookup and looked for an entry for that hostname. You ended seeing the error message from that second failure. I suggest you learn how to use `tcpdump` or wireshark, run that on the MySQL server  (you would run e.g. `tcpdump -nnn port 3306`) and then try to connect from your client, this will allow you to see the same IP address your client connects from that MySQL sees. Also make sure you look for duplicate user/host entries etc. in the MySQL tables (look also for wildcard addresses. 10.10.2.% vs 10.10.2.33 too)

Comment: Thanks nos for your explanation and advice.